# Indefinite integral with multiple values evaluated at endpoints to get definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I am having trouble evaluating the definite integral $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\sin\phi}{\pi\left( 1-\cos^2\Lambda\cos^2\phi \right)}d\Lambda$$ by the standard technique of the difference of value of the indefinite integral $$\int \frac{\sin\phi}{\pi\left( 1-\cos^2\Lambda\cos^2\phi \right)} d\Lambda
  = \frac{1}{\pi} \arctan\left(\frac{\tan\Lambda}{\sin\phi}\right)$$ with integration limits substituted. The arctangent has multiple values, and the argument to it is 0 when $\Lambda=\pm\pi$. If I choose the arctangent value as $0$ for both, I get the wrong answer, but if I choose $\pi$ for the upper limit and 0 for the lower, I get the right answer $1$; it must be nonzero because the integrand is always positive (assuming $\sin\phi > 0$). In Maxima, the definite integral computation gives 1, but substituting the indefinite integral gives 0,

```
 Maxima 5.27.0 http://maxima.sourceforge.net
 (%i1) pdflambda : sin(phi)/(%pi*(1-(cos(Lambda)*cos(phi))^2));
                                    sin(phi)
 (%o1)                  --------------------------------
                                    2            2
                        %pi (1 - cos (Lambda) cos (phi))
 (%i2) assume((cos(phi))^2 - 1.0 < 0);
                                    2
 (%o2)                          [cos (phi) < 1.0]
 (%i3) assume(sin(phi) >= 0);
 (%o3)                           [sin(phi) >= 0]
 (%i4) indefint : trigsimp(integrate(pdflambda,Lambda));
                                    sin(Lambda)
                           atan(--------------------)
                                cos(Lambda) sin(phi)
 (%o4)                     --------------------------
                                      %pi
 (%i5) defint : trigreduce(integrate(pdflambda,Lambda,-%pi,%pi)); 
 (%o5)                                  1
 (%i6) substindef : subst(%pi,Lambda,indefint) - subst(-%pi,Lambda,indefint);
 (%o6)                                  0
```

What are the evaluation rules for selecting the correct value of arctangent? Even using the two-argument arctangent doesn't help here.

Comment: The problem is in a substitution necessary to get to your definite integral. When I was attempting to integrate it manually, I found I had to separate my solution depending on whether $0\le\Lambda\le\pi$ or $-\pi\le\Lambda<0$, the anti-symmetric parts, which would yield the result to $2\int_0^{\pi}(\cdot)$, and after that I had to split it again at $\pi/2$. I didn't go all the way because I have to leave, but this should be the source of the apparent failure of the fundamental law of calculus you were facing (which is not, it's a missing assumption in the expression)

Comment: @Kevin Even splitting integration into multiple intervals, it seems to me you still have to choose from among arctan's multiple values. My puzzle is how that choice is correctly made.